# Change `div` width with JavaScript when `li` is hovered

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a javascript code that make the div width 100% depending on which `li` my mouse is over. Here is my HTML code:

```
<ul class="mylist" >
    <li class="onelist">
        <a href="#">Gallary</a>
        <div></div>
    </li>
    <li >
        <a href="#">Artists</a>
        <div></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Videos</a>
        <div></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <div></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here is my JS code:

```
var list = document.querySelector('ul'),
    li = document.querySelector('li');

list.onmouseenter = function () {
    'use strict';
    li.onmouseenter = function () {
        'use strict';
        this.children[1].style.width = "100%";
    }
}

list.onmouseleave = function () {
    'use strict';
    li.onmouseleave = function () {
        'use strict';
        this.children[1].style.width = "0";
    }
}
```

This code works on the first `li` only. I want it to work on any `li` in my `ul`.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Comment: ok you are right i put my js code that i use but it just apply on the first ( li ) so where do you think the problem

Comment: so did you figure out a way to do this ?

Comment: well, you'd need **all** the `li`'s ... so, for a start, `var allLI = document.querySelectorAll('li')` ... and secondly, you wouldn't nest the onmouse* functions like that

Comment: ok i tried to use like this before var allLI = document.querySelectorAll('li')

but it didn't work at all

Comment: because you don't know what to do with the result - see my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same behaviour with CSS and skip writing the JavaScript altogether.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: i am practicing on using js so i want to do this with js

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to get ALL the `<li>`

so, you'd use

```
var allLi = document.querySelectorAll('li');
```

then, there's no need to have mouseenter/mouseleave functions for the `<UL>` as there's nothing to do on mouse enter/leave

So - now all you need to do is apply your mouse enter/leave logic to all the `<li>`

like:

```
allLi.forEach(function(li) {
    li.onmouseenter = function() {
        'use strict';
         this.children[1].style.width = "100%";
    }
    li.onmouseleave = function() {
        'use strict';
         this.children[1].style.width = "0";
    }
});
```

---

Here's **proof** the code does "work"

```js
var allLi = document.querySelectorAll('li');
allLi.forEach(function(li) {
    li.onmouseenter = function() {
        'use strict';
         this.children[1].style.width = "100%";
    }
    li.onmouseleave = function() {
        'use strict';
         this.children[1].style.width = "0";
    }
});
```

```css
div {
background:red;
width:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mylist" >
    <li class="onelist">
        <a href="#">Gallary</a>
        <div>DIV</div>
    </li>
    <li >
        <a href="#">Artists</a>
        <div>DIV</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Videos</a>
        <div>DIV</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <div>DIV</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: "it didn't work" ... in what way? bit hard to see if empty div's are changing width (that's what your code has)

Comment: at first my code was applying on the first ( li ) only now it didn't apply on any ( li ) 

so my div width stay 0 when i put my mouse on any li

Comment: no it doesn't - see the runnable snippet - although, if you're using internet explorer, then the code wont work as is, it'd need to be transpiled to something that internet explorer understands

Comment: do you mind explain why you write ( function( li ) ) and not just ( function () )

Comment: because `.forEach` calls this callback with each `li` as the argument

Comment: ok , if i want to animate this action i know that setInterval ( function , duration ) so i am confuse about what i should put in the function place

Comment: well, I can't help you there, I don't animate with javascript unless it's something that simply can't be done with CSS transition and/or animation - but that's a completely different question to the one you posted anyway

Comment: ya i know but this is my next step i want to do , i am new in js i used to do this trick with jquery so i just want to do it with js to practice